# Does the fat realization of simplicial spaces commute with finite limits up to homotopy?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

I'm willing to work in the category of compactly generated Hausdorff spaces.

The ordinary geometric realization of a simplicial space commutes with taking pullbacks and preserves the terminal object, hence commute with arbitrary finite limits. (A reference with a proof is Corollary 11.6 in May's 'Geometry of Iterated Loop Space')

It is stated in various places ([Proposition 9 on this page of the nLab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+realization+of+simplicial+topological+spaces), [Remark 2.23 of 'Homotopy Theory of Orbispaces' by Gepner and Henriques](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0701916v1.pdf)) that the fat geometric realization preserves finite limits up to homotopy, but I could not find a solid reference for a proof of this statement. Since it is obvious that it preserves the terminal object up to homotopy, it suffices to have a proof for the pullback-case.

If all simplicial spaces in consideration are 'good' then the statement follows from the preservation for the ordinary realization, but I'm interested in the general case.

Comment: I don't quite understand the vote to close.

Comment: Note that fat realisation preserves pullbacks (but poss with k-topology), just not terminal obj; it gets sent to Δ^\infty

Comment: I do not understand your comment. The fat realization does not even preserve products.

Comment: Products are pullbacks of X→ 1←Y, and 1 but not preserved. More generally, if I'm not wrong, B' should preserve finite _connected_ limits.

Comment: Is there a reference for the preservation of pullbacks? If not, would you mind indicating how to prove it?

Comment: @Simp I'll have to think about it. I can't remember where I got it from!

Comment: It is stated (without a proof or a reference) as Remark 2.23 in "Homotopy Theory of Orbispaces" by David Gepner and @AndréHenriques .